# Play audio in ios using kony FFI

Tags: ios, temenos-quantum

Kindly go through the sample applications embedded in the below link (iOS Native & Kony) for playing the audio and TTS(Text To Speech).

We have integrated iOS FFI for playing the audio and TTS functionality in Kony sample application. Finally we are able to hear the audio is playing when the application is in foreground as well as in background state.

Kindly make the necessary changes in the application as per your use case.

Links for Sample Apps:

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bz-BlA5Z79LVRDlNb0JGOWlyOUU&usp=sharing

Regards,
Guru Murthy

Answer (score 0):

Good sample application for Kony iOS FFI